# How do I generate a sha256 hmac token in ruby with no external modules?

Tags: ruby, shopify, hmac

I am working on an ecommerce website which allows me to create ruby scripts we can run during checkout. The platform doesn't allow native access to any encryption algorithms and they don't allow importing external modules in these scripts. I am trying to generate a sha256 hmac using a secret key from within this ruby script. Is there any ruby code / function I can copy / past to generate a sha256 hmac? I need something relatively small and hopefully not a CPU hog.

I need something like getHash('secret','text')

Comment: Is openssl available there?

Comment: Also do you need HMAC or just regular sha256 hash? These are different.

Comment: honestly I am just trying to add some additional basic security. I dont really need to have sha256 strength. If there is a 10 line ruby snippet that gets me somewhat more secure Ill take what I can get. Ill even use MD5 if that is easy to implement.

Comment: Im no encryption expert. My understanding of sha256 vs hmac is you encrypt a string with some algorithm (sha256/md5/whatever) and hmac just means you compare hashes to verify the original string has not been modified. so technically hmac could use any encryption. Essentially Im trying to create a token and verify the end user could not have generated the token since they dont have access to my secret key

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [OpenSSL::Digest](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Digest.html) and [HMAC](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html) implementation that comes with Ruby.?

```
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, 'secret', 'data')
```

Comment: the platform does not allow import/require/other classes / frameworks / gems. A while back When I try to include openssl shopify 'compiler' complains. I thought I found some couple hundred line implementation of sha256 a while back and I cant find it now. I need something that is pure ruby and no reference to external libraries.

Comment: I assume openssl is written in non ruby binary. If its ruby and its open source I would have to get their source code and paste it in my script. Also there is a limitation of 24k characters.

Comment: What platform do you use? You should at least have any SSL implementation on that platform available.

Comment: [OpenSSL::HMAC](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html) is part of the Ruby Standard Library. If you aren't allowed to use the Ruby Standard Library for some odd reason, then you'll have to roll your own, which is *always* a bad idea and a security risk.

Comment: It's not available and tell that to shopify. I need to roll my own - I thought I was being clear in my post. They block slot of stuff needlessly. Using shopify is always a bad idea and a security risk.